# WPF move Button from StackPanel to Grid cell does not work

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've got a grid (2x2) and Buttons inside of the grid.
I want to move a Button from cell(0,0) to cell (0,1) programmatically.

A: Does work (programmatically)
Move a Button from one grid cell to another grid cell.

B: Does NOT work (programmatically)
Move a Button inside of a StackPanel to a grid cell.

C: Does work (programmatically)
Move the whole StackPanel (with the Button inside) to another grid cell

What can I do?

```
<Window x:Class="CovidGamePrototype.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel  Name="stackPanel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Name="btnTopLeft1"  Content="I am TopLeft 1" Height="Auto" />
        <Button Name="btnTopLeft2"  Content="I am TopLeft 2" Height="Auto" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Button Name="btnBottomLeft" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Content="I am BottomLeft" />
    <Button Name="btnTopRight" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="I am TopRight" />
    <Button Name="btnBottomRight" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="I am BottomRight"/>

</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // does NOT work (move from left to right)
        // this Button is inside of a StackPanel
        Grid.SetColumn(btnTopLeft1, 1);
        Grid.SetZIndex(btnTopLeft1, 5);

        // works (move from left to right)
        Grid.SetColumn(btnBottomLeft, 1);
        Grid.SetZIndex(btnBottomLeft, 5);

        // works (move from left to right)
        // Grid.SetColumn(stackPanel, 1);
        // Grid.SetZIndex(stackPanel, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Grid.Row and Grid.Column attached properties are only effective if the parent element is a Grid. That is obviously not the case when a Button is inside a StackPanel.

Comment: Thank you Clemens for that explanation about the attached properties. But how can I reach the goal to move btnTopLeft1 to another grid cell programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Button` from `StackPanel` and insert the `Button` into the parent of the `StackPanel` which is a `Grid` in your case:

```
stackPanel.Children.Remove(btnTopLeft1);
var grid = (stackPanel.Parent as Grid);
grid?.Children.Add(btnTopLeft1);

Grid.SetColumn(btnTopLeft1, 1);
Grid.SetZIndex(btnTopLeft1, 5);
```